# Client Width is not right

Tags: html

I'm making a mobile website.

I used this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

And here are my devices and the "clientWidth" that they showed

```
.iPhone4(640x960), Safari Browser : 320 x 480
.LG L7(480x800), Google Chrome, FireFox : 320 x 480
.HTC Desire HD (480x800), Google Chrome, FireFox: 320 x 480
.Samsung Galaxy S2 (480x800), Google Chrome, FireFox : 320 x 480
```

Summary: mobile web runs on other devices,browsers but the clientWidth are the same. So how can I use the whole screen device for access my website

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the meta tag there to find the device width, try using Javascript to output `document.width` or `screen.width`.

One of those should contain the number you're looking for.

By setting initial and maximum scale, I think the user will be unable to zoom no matter what. The width=device-width seems superfluous in such a case, as your content can use style="width: 100%" or similar tricks to fill the whole screen. Does this make sense/work for you?

Comment: The metatag that I used is the one I read on The Head First Mobile Web Book. So I think it's useful
Actually the main DIV has width:100%.
But the device is not show their "real resolution" when access website. So the problems come from Screen Device or Browser

Comment: But does my solution of using `document.width` or `screen.width` work?

Comment: How can I use your solution for detecting css files. Please help me

Comment: This (http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/04/targeted-css/) is a good tutorial for doing CSS stuff with mobile browsers and all, but you really shouldn't need that meta tag in order for your CSS content to size properly. It should automatically detect that 100% is 480, or whatever the case may be.